# magento import product to default category

Tags: magento, import

I am using Amartinez Custom Import/export extension.
I am trying to insert to magento 1.6.2 a list of products through a .csv file. I can insert categories just fine, but the problem is that my products don't get added in the "Default category", only in the subcategories of the default category. I have searched as to where i can set that, but i havn't found anything yet.

I've tried adding the "Default category" in the csv, on a new row, and when i ran the cron, it said that a new category called "Default category" was created, but i can't see it anywhere in the categories, and the product is still in the same categories as before.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want them all to show in the default category? 

I am not familiar with that extension, does it allow you to add category Ids? The default category is usually categoryId = 2.

Comment: It's not that i want them all in the default category, but i want them ALSO in the default category, beside the categories that they are in, when i add them through the csv file.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I am asking why you also want them in that category? There's no need for them to be. 
I can see from the code of the module that you can't do this without changes.

Comment: Default Category is not exposed in the front end. you need to add your top categories as a Sub to the Default. So if you want all the products in a single category Like "All Products" put that in the Default then build subs off that.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if Default Category is set to be an anchor, under Catalog > Manage Categories > Select Default Category and click the display settings tab...it's the third dropdown change it to yes.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Itera Research,

I am happy to share reply from our Magento team lead.

Please check below,

- add "category_ids" column to your CSV file and set "Default category" id to this column
  you can lookup Default category id in admin > Catalog > Manage Categories

Happy to chat,

Jen Zorina

Itera Research